# ios - How to close open cells in uitableview through code (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am adding a filter function to my app, but every time a filter is applied a previously opened cell does not close when I change the filter, is there a way to implement this?

I am currently using:

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

to reload the table every time the filter is applied

To open and close:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            // only first row toggles exapand/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];


            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

            }
            else
            {

                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                NSLog(@"Section:%d", rows);
            }

            for (int i=1; i<rows; i++)
            {
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                               inSection:section];
                NSLog(@"INDEX: %@", tmpIndexPath);
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (currentlyExpanded)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                });
            }
            else
            {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                  });

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Add the code of open/close

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before tableview `reloadData` clear the `expandedSections` array.

```
[expandedSections removeAllIndexes];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

`expandedSections` Array maintains the status of the expand section details.Due to that its not collapse the view. So clear the array before reload the table view.

Comment: get the error: No visible @interface for 'NSMutableIndexSet' declares the selector 'removeAllObjects'

Comment: As it is a `NSMutableIndexSet` you have to use `removeAllIndexes`. Updated the answer also